# Footer to the bottom of the page after min-height main area

Tags: css, html, footer

I'm currently working with a webpage and I run into a problem. I want my footer to stay at the bottom of the page, after the main area. The problem is that I want the main area to be at `min-height:900px;` and it will be slightly over the footer.

If I add more text to the main area it scales well, but the footer is now set to stay in `margin-top:1190px;` How could I get it to follow the main area if more text is added?

The page prototype is here: http://goo.gl/tu6s9

Comment: can you post your desired result image for better understanding of your problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2130814 Change Your Web Page CSS Like This

```
#logomenu {
    display: block;
    height: 98px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#intro {
    display: block;
    height: 198px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sisalto {
       background-color: #E8E8E8;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 900px;
opacity: 0.9;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 30px;
position: relative;
right: 0;
width: 900px;


 }

 #footer {
    background-image: url("images/bottom.jpg");
    clear: both;
    height: 215px;
    min-width: 1100px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

#footersisennys {
    display: block;
    height: 145px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    width: 900px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: It broke the site, but the footer is now staying at the bottom. So close hmm... Adding these to the #sisalto it fixes the page width:900px;
margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:-30px;
z-index:5; but now the problem is that the sisalto doesnt scale with the text

Comment: This is what happens now http://80.221.23.225:8080/testi/ it's better but the sisalto doesnt scale with the text, text is actually overflowing the div

Comment: Problem solved. After the corrected css I had to add empty div which clears everything. 
<div style="clear: both; height: 20px;"></div>

Comment: @user2130814 change the css of #sisalto like this  #sisalto {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 900px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    width: 900px;
}

Comment: @user2130814  I am glad that you were able to complete it. Please mark my response as the answer if it is the guidance that provided to solution.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work straight away but helped to correct the page. Thanks!